# Copy file path to terminal without escape sequences in mac

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have a perl script that takes input file path from the terminal. So, while entering the file path, I can drag and drop the file to the terminal (Mac). If I have file paths like

- /Users/San/abc(ev50)_xyz.tif,

then dragging and dropping the file will result in

- /Users/San/abc\(ev50\)_xyz.tif

being pasted on the terminal. Is there a way to copy paste (drag and drop) the file path as is? I saw in some of the forums, they had mentioned about creating a service and so on. But, I want to know if there is an easy way to paste it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Drag/drop enters the filename, with characters that might present problems to shell scripts escaped with backslashes (such as bash).  Reading the filename directly, you of course do not have this problem.  The solution is to remove the extra backslashes, e.g., as done in [@Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40468/ether)'s answer to *[How can I unescape backslashes in a Perl string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115788/4518274)*.