# How can I substitute double backslash with 1?

Tags: regex, perl

Having a string that has the backslash escaped i.e. `\\` how can I make it single backslash?
The `$string =~ s/\\/\/g;` does not work.

Comment: `s/\\\\/\\/g` - you also have to escape the backslash in the regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I unescape backslashes in a Perl string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115398/how-can-i-unescape-backslashes-in-a-perl-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need four backslashes as the backslash itself needs to be escaped as well:

```
$string =~ s/\\\\/\\/g
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mP7gQ9/2).

---

A complete example in `Perl`:

```
my $string = 'this is a double backslash: \\\\';
print $string . "\n";
$string =~ s/\\\\/\\/g;
print $string;
```

See the [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/poOtIN).